# Reading type "struct tm" from binary file using Python

Tags: python

I am trying  to read the time at which a binary file was saved from information in the binary file. This information is stored as a type "struct tm" of size eighteen bytes --

```
struct tm
{
    int tm_sec; // seconds [0,61]
    int tm_min; // minutes [0,59]
    int tm_hour; // hour [0,23]
    int tm_mday; // day of month [1,31]
    int tm_mon; // month of year [0,11]
    int tm_year; // years since 1900 
    int tm_wday; // day of week [0,6] (Sunday = 0)
    int tm_yday; // day of year [0,365]
    int tm_isdst; // daylight savings flag
};
```

I have tried using the `struct` module for Python. I'm also reading the binary file for other values using this module, and this has worked well, but for discrete float values of four bytes each. I have used the following code to try and read the integer values in struct tm

```
time_tgt = struct.unpack('9h', binconts[160:(160 + 18)])[0]
```

Bin counts refer here to the offset (160), and the range, which is 160+(size of the data type, which here is 18).
My thought process here is that, at 18 bytes, each of the nine components of `struct tm` consists of 2 bytes, so a short integer using `h` as the argument for struct.unpack. However, I've had no luck in returning a series of value, which is what I would expect.

Is `struct` the appropriate tool to use? Is `struct tm` here a string of values which individually is composed of `int` values but which are amalgameted into one type?

Comment: It's entirely possible that your `struct.unpack()` call worked just fine - but then you threw away all but the first value with that `[0]`.

Comment: It was indeed. Thank you for noting that.